aws S3 video/image download/serve
so as the title suggest , am trying to make it possible in my Nextjs app to get files from s3 and make them downloadable and also show them.
the current problem am having is the following : even though the links am getting are working fine , if the file is an image it will get downloaded but won't show on the frontend , if its a video it will neither show nor download .
i tried testing the links from postman, i was able to download both .
however when i post the links on the browser i get the MIME type not supported .
through postman the video type is clearly mp4
through browser 

you can get the content type by the extention and then change content type by something like
s3Instance.getObject({   Bucket: "my-bucket",   Key: "MyXMLFile",   ContentType: "text/xml" }, function(err, data) {   //callback here });

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Video not shown after serving it from s3 , header indicates the content type is video/mp4 but when shown in the browser it shows the following : Unsupported file type or Mime type not supported ( images however are shown normally at this stage ( after fixing the upload process to attach headers for files )

Hard to tell without a detailed debug session, but what I would look at first is the Content-Type header in the response.  If it’s not correct (e.g. image/jpeg, video/mpeg etc.), the browser cannot figure out what to do with it.
To check, put the URL into Postman, click Send, and then look at the Headers tab.  It should have a row with the key Content-Type and an appropriate value.
If the row is not present or or the value is not appropriate, consult the S3 documentation for how to correct it.    If everything looks all right, your problem lies elsewhere.

am returning a json with 2 url links for image/video and a csv file . am not specifically using the api to get one thing .

@ZacNeley — yes, your problem might be in how S3 is responding to the URL.  See my edit to my answer.

the Content type row returned " binary/octet-stream"

Well there’s your problem.  binary/octet-stream is basically “Der, I dunno.”  You have to alter your upload process to mark the files with content-types before the files will be usable.

so i changed the process for uploading files now the type is correct. the images are being shown however the videos are still having uncorrect mime type / file type not supported even though the header got video/mp4 as the content type

@ZacNeley — how odd.  What you need to do — after you have double-checked for typos and such — is find another video on another website and see what header it has, and use that.

@ZacNeley — also, make sure the video is not corrupted and is MPEG4 and not some other format: download it to your machine and see if you can play it directly and the file command agrees with the type.

tried that ,file opens fine  and the format is mp4, i don't know if this will help but am using firefox also tried it on edge same thing

@ZacNeley — weird.  All I can recommend is find a different site where a different video renders correctly and track down the differences.
